# Can a Fakevim tag be added?

Tags: discussion, tags

Fakevim exists in QtCreator, and I have a few questions specifically pertinent to it.

There is no tag for it yet though, and I have not enough reputation to create it.

Comment: Not sure what your questions are, but they may not be on-topic; see: [what is considered to be vi?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/7/51).

Answer (score 3):

Until there is a question that warrants the tag (and which is also on-topic and appropriate), there's no reason to "pre-declare" the tag. It's usually a slippery slope and not the greatest idea.